# jQuery Date Format Validation (Highlight The Text Field)

Tags: jquery, validation, date-format

I have a date textbox on an html page. I want to validate it on run time using jQuery for the format dd-mm-yyyy. If the enter the invalid format the textbox background should turn red.

I'm using the following but failed to do so.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#submit').click(function () {
  var dateReg = /^\d{2}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$/;

  if(!dateReg.test(date.val())){
    date.addClass('highlight');
    jQuery(date).focus();
    return false;
  } else date.removeClass('highlight');
}); 
});
</script>

<style>
    .highlight { background: #FFE6E7; }
</style>

<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="date"/> <em>(dd-mm-yyyy)</em><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

...

I tried it but unable to achieve it :(
Secondly I want it to be validate as soon as the user enters the value. Not onclick of submit.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

your regex is fine but your jQuery isnt:

```
jQuery('#date').focus
```

and you could use on keypress:

```
jQuery('#submit').keypress
```

or you can use focus out, it is triggered when lost focus:

```
jQuery('#submit').focusout
```

but be sure always to check backend! annyone can disable javascript

Comment: Ok, I fixed it myself. I made an entirely new code. So I'm going to share it here so others can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new code myself. It is working on OnClick of submit button too, but the purpose of highlighting it achieved.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#btnSubmit').bind('click', function(){
        var txtVal =  $('#txtDate').val();
        if(isDate(txtVal))
            $('#txtDate').removeClass('highlight');            
        else
            $('#txtDate').addClass('highlight');
    });

function isDate(txtDate)
{
    var currVal = txtDate;
    if(currVal == '')
        return false;

    var rxDatePattern = /^(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{1,2})(\/|-)(\d{4})$/; //Declare Regex
    var dtArray = currVal.match(rxDatePattern); // is format OK?

    if (dtArray == null) 
        return false;

    //Checks for dd/mm/yyyy format.
    dtDay = dtArray[1];
    dtMonth= dtArray[3];
    dtYear = dtArray[5];        

    if (dtDay < 1 || dtDay > 31) 
        return false;
    else if (dtMonth < 1 || dtMonth> 12) 
        return false;
    else if ((dtMonth==4 || dtMonth==6 || dtMonth==9 || dtMonth==11) && dtDay ==31) 
        return false;
    else if (dtMonth == 2) 
    {
        var isleap = (dtYear % 4 == 0 && (dtYear % 100 != 0 || dtYear % 400 == 0));
        if (dtDay> 29 || (dtDay ==29 && !isleap)) 
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}
});
</script>


<style>
.highlight { background-color:#FFE6E7; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<br/><br/>
Date : <input type="text" id="txtDate" /> (dd/mm/yyyy)
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="ValidateDate" id="btnSubmit"/>
</body>

</html>
```